# Is there an idiomatic way of avoiding `Box::leak` with this code?

Tags: memory-leaks, rust

As I continue to learn Rust I'm working on a project which involves extensive use of predicate functions. I've decided to implement these predicates with Rust closures, e.g.:

`type Predicate = Box<Fn(&Form) -> bool>`.

My program uses boolean logic applied to these predicates. For instance, both `and` as well as `or` are applied over the value of these predicates. I've made this work using `Box::leak`:

```
struct Form {
    name: String,
}

fn and(a: Option<Predicate>, b: Option<Predicate>) -> Option<Predicate> {
    if a.is_none() {
        return b;
    } else if b.is_none() {
        return a;
    } else {
        let a = Box::leak(a.unwrap());
        let b = Box::leak(b.unwrap());
        return Some(Box::new(move |form: &Form| a(form) && b(form)));
    }
}
```

While this seems to work as I'd like, `Box::leak` seems non-ideal. I don't know enough about `std::rc::Rc` and `std::cell::RefCell` to know if these might help me avoid `Box::leak` here — employing them might require significant restructuring of my code, but I'd like to at least understand what the idiomatic approach here might be.

Is there a way of avoiding the leak while still maintaining the same functionality?

Here's [the complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=baac4f0ac7eebdfeef5bf1738486f550):

```
struct Form {
    name: String,
}

type Predicate = Box<Fn(&Form) -> bool>;

struct Foo {
    predicates: Vec<Predicate>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn and(a: Option<Predicate>, b: Option<Predicate>) -> Option<Predicate> {
        if a.is_none() {
            return b;
        } else if b.is_none() {
            return a;
        } else {
            let a = Box::leak(a.unwrap());
            let b = Box::leak(b.unwrap());
            return Some(Box::new(move |form: &Form| a(form) && b(form)));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pred = Foo::and(
        Some(Box::new(move |form: &Form| {
            form.name == String::from("bar")
        })),
        Some(Box::new(move |_: &Form| true)),
    )
    .unwrap();
    let foo = Foo {
        predicates: vec![pred],
    };
    let pred = &foo.predicates[0];
    let form_a = &Form {
        name: String::from("bar"),
    };
    let form_b = &Form {
        name: String::from("baz"),
    };
    assert_eq!(pred(form_a), true);
    assert_eq!(pred(form_b), false);
}
```

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust does not use explicit `return`s.

Comment: Do you know that you can overload the and operator (`&`)? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitAnd.html

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not need `Box::leak` and it's unclear why you think it does. The code continues to compile and have the same output if it's removed:

```
impl Foo {
    fn and(a: Option<Predicate>, b: Option<Predicate>) -> Option<Predicate> {
        if a.is_none() {
            b
        } else if b.is_none() {
            a
        } else {
            let a = a.unwrap();
            let b = b.unwrap();
            Some(Box::new(move |form: &Form| a(form) && b(form)))
        }
    }
}
```

The `unwrap`s are non-idiomatic; a more idiomatic solution would use `match`:

```
impl Foo {
    fn and(a: Option<Predicate>, b: Option<Predicate>) -> Option<Predicate> {
        match (a, b) {
            (a, None) => a,
            (None, b) => b,
            (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(Box::new(move |form| a(form) && b(form))),
        }
    }
}
```